# Meaning of 하루 동안 하는 걱정의 반

Tags: translation

In this sentence, what is the meaning of 반?

> 사람이 하루 동안 하는 걱정의 반 이상은 쓸데없는 걱정이라고 한다.

Is it just "half"? If so, is it describing 하루 and would this be the proper translation?

> People say that worrying for more than half the day is unnecessary worrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here 반 does mean half, but it doesn't describe 하루, but rather 걱정.
In general, when you have "A의 반", it means "half of A".

So I would translate this as:

> They say that half of the worries that people have throughout the day are unnecessary worries.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense (and is a lot more logical grammatically)!

Answer (score 2):

반 means "half" in this sentence.

It is describing "걱정".

I would translate it as this:

> It is said that more than half of worries a person has during the day is useless.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the other answer only because it was first :)